# Почему Telegram-бот не видит переменные окружения?

Tags: python, linux, telegram-bot, .env

Есть Telegram-бот, написанный на языке **Python**. Для обеспечения безопасности, какие-либо конфигурационные настройки я вынес в файл `/etc/environment`.
Проблема в том, что Бот видит эти переменные только при ручном запуске исполняемого файла. При попытке запустить бота через файл-сервис, он терпит неудачу, так как все переменные окружения возвращают **NoneType*". Что это может быть?

Файл `config.py`:

```
import os

API_TOKEN = os.getenv('API_KEY_TWO')

ADMIN_ID = os.getenv('ADMIN_IDS').split(' ')

POSTGRES_CONFIG = {
    'host': os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST'),
    'user': os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER'),
    'password': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
    'port': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT'),
    'database': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DATABASE_TWO')
}

REDIS_CONFIG = {
    'address': os.getenv('REDIS_ADDRESS'),
}
```

Файл /etc/environment/:

```
API_KEY_ONE="1333415565:AAEb0gAeXYs1***********************"
API_KEY_TWO="1382393718:AAHl-k_J5LqR***********************"

ADMIN_IDS="434903526 250020439"

POSTGRES_HOST="l*******t"
POSTGRES_USER="*********"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="*******"
POSTGRES_PORT=5432

POSTGRES_DATABASE_ONE="aiogram_bot"
POSTGRES_DATABASE_TWO="aiogram_bot_excel"

REDIS_ADDRESS="redis://localhost"
```

Код ошибки:

```
Sep 23 01:51:19 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: aiogram_bot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 23 01:51:19 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: aiogram_bot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: aiogram_bot.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: aiogram_bot.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: Stopped Aiogram Database Bot.
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: Started Aiogram Database Bot.
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru python3.8[634]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru python3.8[634]:   File "app.py", line 6, in <module>
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru python3.8[634]:     from config.config import ADMIN_ID, REDIS_CONFIG
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru python3.8[634]:   File "/home/cesoneemz/aiogram_bot/config/config.py", line 5, in <module>
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru python3.8[634]:     ADMIN_ID = os.getenv('ADMIN_IDS').split('')
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru python3.8[634]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: aiogram_bot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: aiogram_bot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 23 01:51:29 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: aiogram_bot.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 23 01:51:29 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: aiogram_bot.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Sep 23 01:51:29 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: Stopped Aiogram Database Bot.
```

Comment: если кратко, systemd (как и другие системы инициализации) не подцепляет среду из `/etc/environment`... для модуля systemd переменные среды можно установить как-то так: https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service . В данном случае я бы рекомендовал способ с `EnvironmrntFile`... а ещё держать квазисекретные данные в переменных среды — не самая хорошая идея с точки зрения паранойи...

Answer (score 0):

ну как бы по логу

```
Sep 23 01:51:24 351354-cq47489.tmweb.ru python3.8[634]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Пересмотрите

```
ADMIN_ID = os.getenv('ADMIN_IDS').split(' ')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]